# How can I access Google Docs spreadsheets in Android?

Tags: google-drive

I have spreadsheets in Google Docs and I want to access them without using the browser.  How can I do this?

There is an application on the Android Market called "MS GDocs" which is good but it's only for documents, not for spreadsheets.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the browser?  Is there a specific feature missing from the mobile version, or do you want offline access?

Comment: because i don't want to open browser and do authentication again an again. I want "MS GDocs" kind application. One think is that in most of browse i can see only one spread sheet per work book, i have some work book and if i want to create work sheet on it then some browser does not allow to do it.

Answer (score 7):

There is now an actual Google Docs application in the Market made by Google. You can take a look at it in the Market online here: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&feature=search_result - I've used it and it's pretty similar to the online look, but with a more native feel. Hopefully, this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

[QuickOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qo.android.am3) supports downloading Google spreadsheets, editing them, and then uploading the edited file.  I'm not sure if it will create a new document on upload or replace the other one.